# Proving the existence of set

Tags: number-theory

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb N$.$A$ contains 5 elements.sum of any three elements is prime.does $A$ exists ?please give some hints .

Comment: No, as any element summed with itself thrice is multiple of 3 and not prime.

Comment: @AsharTafhim has an excellent answer, but if you mean the sum of three distinct elements should be prime, then too  the answer is no, by considering remainders modulo three (i.e. prove that in a set of five integers, there are three of them whose sum adds up to a multiple of  $3$).

Comment: @AsharTafhim I suppose that th OP meant three *distinct* elements.